# Multi-page with Tabulary?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabulary

I know that you can combine `tabularx` and `longtable` functionality with either `ltxtable` or `ltablex`, but is there something similar for `tabulary`? My searching has come up dry when looking for any way to get `tabulary` to work with very long tables.

The table I am working with has large amounts of text that requires line breaking in multiple columns. Some cells have very little, and some have a lot, and I would like to see the column widths juggled to minimize total table length. I realize I could manually do this with the `{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}` functionality in `tabularx`, but what I'm making is intended to be a template that should work well with any particular arrangement of data that gets thrown in. Am I doomed to using `tabularx` and manually adjusting the hsize numbers each time I want to make a table?

Comment: TX isn't _that_ bad: "doomed" probably isn't the word I'd use:-) If you don't need table headers repeated at the page breaks you could just inbox the TY table. If you do need headings probably isn't impossibly difficult to modify ltxtable so that it mixes TY and longtable instead of TX, but I'm busy this week so someone else might like the challenge:-)

Comment: Yeah, the repeated table headers are unfortunately pretty key. I manually defined a few p columns in TX that pretty well handle things, but there is still an l column I can imagine getting a little strange in fringe cases that I'm not sure I can bear to hard code a width for.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For those that don’t need the table headers repeated at page breaks, could you explain what “just inbox[ing]” a `tabulary` table means? Is wrapping in something like `\mbox` what does the trick?

Answer (score 19):

Updated to support setting `longtable` `\LTleft` and `\LTright` margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabulary}
\setlength\textheight{10\baselineskip}
\topmargin-4\baselineskip
\headheight0pt
\pdfpageheight18\baselineskip

\def\a{Red green blue yellow green. }
\def\b{One two three four five six. }
\makeatletter

\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}

\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{ltabulary}{LLL}
HEAD 1& HEAD 2& HEAD 3\endhead
\a\a&\a&\a\a\a\\
\b\b&\b&\b\b\b\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
\b\b&\a&\b\a\b\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
\end{ltabulary}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\LTleft=2cm

\begin{ltabulary}{LLL}
HEAD 1& HEAD 2& HEAD 3\endhead
\a\a&\a&\a\a\a\\
\b\b&\b&\b\b\b\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
\b\b&\a&\b\a\b\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
x&y&z\\
\end{ltabulary}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The only problem with it is that it removes all the hyphenations. Is it possible to have them back? It is especially true for the cases when there is a long word in a narrow column.

Comment: @v_2e tabulary `L` column is same as `\begin{flushleft}` which prefers leaving a line short over hyphenation, you can use `J` columns instead for justified columns with hyphenation (the usual latex default). words longer than the column width would hyphenate with either L or J but the first word of a paragraph doesn't hyphenate in TeX start the text with `\hspace*{0pt}` to get round that (true in general not just in this sort of table)

Comment: To make captions work with this, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197808/60839) answer.

Comment: I probably should've realized this before finding it the hard way, but threeparttable and David's ltabulary aren't compatible. The document builds, but if the ltabulary is inside the threeparttable it won't break at page end.

Comment: This works excellent. I ended up using it quite heavily. Perhaps you should make an official release (with caption fix)

Comment: What is about the official release? Is there an official package for this solution?

Comment: I guess the part between `\makeatletter … \makeatother` is all that’s needed for the implementation, and then the part between `\begin{ltabulary} … \end{ltabulary}` is the usage, which is as simple as changing `tabulary` to `ltabulary` and dropping the length before the preamble, which doesn’t seem to be supported. Are there any other limitations with such a short implementation?

Comment: @caw well the things that are not supported are mainly the longtable style table head and foot rows, and also (less of an issue now than when longtable was written) the whole table needs to be grabbed as an argument and so be held in memory, longtable is designed so that you can have thousands of lines without ever holding a row in macro token memory.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code (of course) works perfectly and this solution is excellent – just as your help and advice here in general. It just wasn’t immediately obvious that `\begin{ltabulary}{\textwidth}{lcr}` only works with the first revision of your answer, while the support for `\LTleft` and `\LTright` from the second revision is a *replacement* for the `length` argument and you must therefore use `\begin{ltabulary}{lcr}` with that revision.