# Several caption problems in longtable and tabulary

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tabulary

I'm trying to typeset some multipage tables with tablenotes and repeating captions on each page. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary) question, which marries the `longtable` environment with `tabulary`. This is quite nice, because then I don't need to take care of the column widths myself, but can use one of the `LRJC` options of `tabulary` to do that for me.

In the following MWE, almost everything works out nicely, but there are some caption problems.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain}

\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs, longtable, ltcaption}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
\makeatletter
\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{TableNotes}
%   \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%   \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \captionof{table}{Example of long table over multiple pages}
    \begin{ltabulary}{rLlcccc}
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide and wider and wider and wider and wider & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    \end{ltabulary}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above code compiles fine, but I have to use `\captionof` which produce problems 2 to 4. If I replace it with `\caption{Example of long table over multiple pages}`, I get the errors in problem 1.

These are the problems:

1. I cannot use the `\caption{}` command. It gives me `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float`. This is the case regardless if I use the `caption` package or not. Also, the placement does not matter. I can put it inside the `ltabulary` environment or outside, both times it gives me the same error. I suspect that, since `longtable` uses its own caption command and it's not included in the definition of `ltabulary` from the question, it does not work. If that is the case, the error makes sense, because `longtable` is not set inside a float which `\caption` needs. I worked around this by using the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package, but this comes with its own problems:
2. The spacing between the caption and the table is too big compared to the other two tables. This can be fixed with `\vspace{-12pt}`, but it's rather tedious to do that for each table.
3. The numbering of subsequent tables is wrong. The third table in the MWE is numbered 4 instead of 3. I suspect this is a problem with longtable and `\captionof`, because longtable sets a new table for each page which increases the table counter. This can be fixed with `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`, but this is, again, rather tedious.
4. I cannot repeat the caption for each page, because `\captionof` inside the `ltabulary` environment gives me an error: `! Missing \endgroup inserted`. I could probably fix this by setting the caption manually, but this is even more tedious, because if I move a table, I have to go back to each table and adjust the numbering. It should also not repeat the whole caption for each page, but add something along the lines of "Table 2 (continued)".

Is there some wizard here who can add the `\caption` command to the `ltabulary` definition (which would presumably fix all the problems above in one go), or fix it some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my utter surprise, I actually managed to patch the code for the `ltabulary` environment to add support for the `\caption` command. The patched code is taken from the [`ltxtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) package with very minor changes and comprises a whooping 3 lines.

The below code solves all problems in one go, as suggested in the first problem in the question. Replace the corresponding code in the MWE with this one, convert the `\captionof` command into a `\caption` command and move it inside the `ltabulary` environment.

```
%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)
% with modifications taken from the ltxtable package to make captions work
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\TY@cap@gobble[2][]{\\}% from ltxtable (adjusted)
\def\ltabulary{%
    \def\caption{% from ltxtable (adjusted)
        \@ifstar\TY@cap@gobble\TY@cap@gobble}
    \def\endfirsthead{\\}%
    \def\endhead{\\}%
    \def\endfoot{\\}%
    \def\endlastfoot{\\}%
    \def\tabulary{%
        \def\TY@final{%
    \def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
    \def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
    \def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
    \def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
    \longtable}%
        \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
        \TY@tabular}%
    \dimen@\columnwidth
    \advance\dimen@-\LTleft
    \advance\dimen@-\LTright
    \tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain}

\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs, longtable, ltcaption, ltabptch}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)
% with modifications taken from the ltxtable package to make captions work
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\TY@cap@gobble[2][]{\\}% from ltxtable (adjusted)
\def\ltabulary{%
    \def\caption{% from ltxtable (adjusted)
        \@ifstar\TY@cap@gobble\TY@cap@gobble}
    \def\endfirsthead{\\}%
    \def\endhead{\\}%
    \def\endfoot{\\}%
    \def\endlastfoot{\\}%
    \def\tabulary{%
        \def\TY@final{%
    \def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
    \def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
    \def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
    \def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
    \longtable}%
        \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
        \TY@tabular}%
    \dimen@\columnwidth
    \advance\dimen@-\LTleft
    \advance\dimen@-\LTright
    \tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{TableNotes}
%   \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%   \setlength\LTright{0pt}
%   \captionof{table}{Example of long table over multiple pages}
    \begin{ltabulary}{rLlcccc}
        \caption{Example of long table over multiple pages}\\
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide and wider and wider and wider and wider & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{(continued)}\\
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    \end{ltabulary}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here, excerpts of the result which did not work before:

[image: Table 2 caption]
[image: Table 2 (continued) caption]
[image: Table 3 correct numbering]

If I feel daring, I might convert this to an actual package.

Answer (score 0):

Well I read your MWE code and the first two lines repeated once, I erased from the MWE, later I copied the code and compile on my machine without errors. The first time only the second table gives an error showing the footnote in very narrow column. But the second time all look good.

I fear the errors your reported come from those duplicated lines in your code, in my case this is the code I compile:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs,longtable,ltcaption}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

%% define a new envrionment which marries longtable with tabulary
\makeatletter
\def\ltabulary{%
\def\endfirsthead{\\}%
\def\endhead{\\}%
\def\endfoot{\\}%
\def\endlastfoot{\\}%
\def\tabulary{%
  \def\TY@final{%
\def\endfirsthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}%
\def\endhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@head}%
\def\endfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@foot}%
\def\endlastfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lastfoot}%
\longtable}%
  \let\endTY@final\endlongtable
  \TY@tabular}%
\dimen@\columnwidth
\advance\dimen@-\LTleft
\advance\dimen@-\LTright
\tabulary\dimen@}
\def\endltabulary{\endtabulary}
\makeatother
% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary (see there for usage)


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{TableNotes}
%   \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%   \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \captionof{table}{Example of long table over multiple pages}
    \begin{ltabulary}{rLlcccc}
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide and wider and wider and wider and wider & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \toprule
        cell 1 & cell with linebreaks if it gets too wide & cell 3 & cell 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
    \end{ltabulary}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\begin{table}
    \caption{Nice long caption directly above the start of the table with lots of...}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LlLLL}
        \toprule
        top cell one with title & top cell two with title & longtop with note & top cell four with title & top cell five with title\\
        \midrule
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        cell & cell & big long cell stuff & cell & more cell\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \note This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines. This is a long explanation going over multiple lines.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I used `Sublime Text 2` with `LaTeXtools` package for compile it. My machine uses `Ubuntu 14.04`as SO and I use `TeXlive 2013`. If I open a terminal and I use `pdflatex` directly the result is the same.

[image: Table 1]
[image: Tabla 2]
[image: Tabla 4]

Comment: Ah, sorry, we have a misunderstanding here. I edited the question to make it clearer. Basically, The MWE compiles fine, but it uses the `\captionof` command to get a caption in the second table. But that produces problems 2 to 4 (see your pictures, I have the same output). I'd like to use the longtable `\caption` command to eliminate these, but that gives me problem 1.