# Can LaTeX automatically determine column widths?

Tags: tables

I want to generate a nice PDF automatically. It mostly works really well, mainly the tables are missing.

I just realized that I don't know any way to get a decent column width automatically. Do you know one?

(I could use Python before)

### Minimal Example 1: The default table

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    Lorem & Long \\\hline
    ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    foo   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    bar   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

### Minimal Example 2: HTML

To show that it can be done better, I made structurally the same table with HTML and printed it with Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Lorem</th>
        <th>Long</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

gives

[image]

Obviously, this is much better.

### Minimal Example 3: tabularx

`tabularx` with the `X` column spaces the columns at least evenly and makes the cells break lines, but it does not move the cells width so that the total table length is minizmized:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    Lorem & Long \\\hline
    ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    foo   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    bar   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, `pandoc table.html -o table.pdf` gives a [bad result](https://imgur.com/a/CSIhL)

Comment: You should try with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}`.

Comment: The Python package [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) gives reasonable results ... so wasyprint + pdfcrop might be one way to automatically get reasonable tables.

Comment: @Werner My usecase is more complicated. Most of the time many columns. It is not necessarily the first column which is small. So would your approach work when the contents of columns would be switched, but the column definition line not? Or if the first column contained a bit more text - just enough to get to the middle of the page?

Comment: The column-definition {lX} will make one l-column which is as wide as its content and one X-column which will use the remaining space on the line. If you switch the content you will also have to switch the definition to {Xl}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Which is exactly my point. I wrote a program which automatically generates the LaTeX code. Completely. I don't know anything about the tables as a developer. To clarify - my program has all of the content, but I can't make assumptions about the content. So I have a list of lists of strings where each sub-list has equal length.

Comment: Try the tabulary package.

Comment: @MartinThoma: In answer to the question you asked: Yes. LaTeX can determine column widths automatically. But you have to provide some guidance in terms of the column specification for it to do that properly. Alternatively, one could process the table multiple times and based on some analysis determine what column specification to use. But that's not easy, and seem like you can do that outside of LaTeX more readily.

Answer (score 4):

try tabulary rather than tabularx it is closer to what html does (although not a lot closer:-) But it was written for the use case you describe of flowing unknown content into tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\setlength\tymin{50pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|J|J|}
    \hline
    Lorem & Long \\\hline
    ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    foo   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    bar   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\\hline
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\linewidth` and `\textwidth`?

Comment: While this is closer to the solution I need, it still has one severe problem: If the table is very long, breaking it into multiple pages is not done. Does `longtable` have something similar to `J`?

Comment: you can find a page breaking version of tabulary on this site I think...

Comment: @MartinThoma https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary/87409#87409

Comment: @MartinThoma `\linewidth` is the width of the current line and `\textwidth` is the width of the text block on the page. So they are different in two column or in an indented list or in a minipage or parbox or ...