# How to auto-size longtable columns

Tags: tables, longtable, columns, column-width

I'm using `longtable` to break a table across multiple pages of my document. In HTML, I can do something like this to simplify the formatting of my table:

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        <td>Ut enim ad minim veniam,</td>
        <td>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This gives something that looks like this:
[image]
The column widths are automatically adjusted in proportion to the length of the text in each column, line breaks are permitted, *and* the width of the table is exactly the width of the page. **How can I accomplish these three things *with the `longtable` environment* (or some other environment that allows tables to break across pages) in LaTeX?**

Comment: there is some code to combine longtable and tabulary here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87409/2388. But I never tried it. I prefer to tweak the width manually for the best result.